# Using str.format(name='text'), unexpectedly adding a '\n' at the end

Tags: python, string, format

I have a text file that I am reading and iterating through line by line.

Lets say the txt file reads:

```
hello,

my name is {name}.
my address is {address}.

thank you for listening.
```

here is the code I am using:

```
def read_function (given_name, given_address):
    output = []
    file = open(r"directory\etc..", "r")
    for line in file:
        output.append(line.format(name=given_name, address=given_address)

    print ("".join(output))
```

the problem I am having is that when it prints it will actually print as follows:

```
hello,

my name is Susan
.
my address is 123 mars road
.

thank you for listening.
```

seems as though the formatting is adding a '\n' to right after the named format. 
Is that how that works? is there a way to NOT do that?

Comment: What's `given_name`? Does it contain a `\n`?

Comment: seems like `given_name` and `given_address` have the extra `\n`... Use the `strip()` function to "cleanup" the strings... the formatting seems correct

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.format I think @Daniel is right, `given_name` and `address` must have a `\n` at the end. How are you setting them?

Comment: print appends a newline, and the given_name already ends with a newline. Your could use `strip()` (which removes leading white spaces too), or try using `,` which adds a smart space to the end of the line

Comment: WOW. I cant believe I didnt think of that. thank you. Im using Tkinter to make a gui that auto generates emails based on certain inputs (ticket numbers, business address, etc).

Didnt realize when I was getting the string in the Text box that it contained a \n.

Comment: added a strip('\n') when passing the variable to the above function and everythings cleaned up. thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
output.append(line.format(
    name=given_name.strip('\n'),
    address=given_address.strip('\n'))
)
```

to keep `name` and `address` without trailing newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.rstrip()` to remove trailing whitespace characters (including `\n`) from the parameter strings. Also, you can simplify the function by using `file.read()` to read the whole format string at once:

```
def read_function(given_name, given_address):
    with open(r"directory\etc..") as f:
        format_str = f.read()
        print(format_str.format(name=given_name.rstrip(),
                                address=given_address.rstrip())
```

Comment: One should strip the newline, when reading `given_name`, and not when using it.